# kivy crashes when i run it on android

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I have a problem. The app I made with kivy crashes when I run it on android, I used ubuntu to create the apk.
When I run it, logcat throws me this error:
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused).
So I decided to create a host in the cloud for the database and it doesn't give me any more errors but the app keeps closing. can anybody help me?

Once I realized that the database was not connecting, I changed it and hoped that it would work well.

this shows me the logcat

01-21 21:03:38.339 10162 10190 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
01-21 21:03:38.339 10162 10190 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
01-21 21:03:38.339 10162 10190 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
01-21 21:03:38.339 10162 10190 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app
01-21 21:03:38.345 10162 10190 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
01-21 21:03:38.345 10162 10190 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
01-21 21:03:38.345 10162 10190 I python  : calculated paths to be...
01-21 21:03:38.345 10162 10190 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
01-21 21:03:38.349 10162 10190 I python  : set wchar paths...
01-21 21:03:38.424 10162 10190 I python  : Initialized python
01-21 21:03:38.424 10162 10190 I python  : AND: Init threads
01-21 21:03:38.424 10162 10190 I python  : testing python print redirection
01-21 21:03:38.426 10162 10190 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
01-21 21:03:38.426 10162 10190 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/apex/com.android.art/bin:/system_ext/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_ART_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.art', 'ANDROID_I18N_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.i18n', 'ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.tzdata', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/framework-atb-backward-compatibility.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar:/system/framework/moto-echolocateapi.jar:/system/framework/payjoy-api.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar:/apex/com.android.mediaprovider/javalib/framework-mediaprovider.jar:/apex/com.android.os.statsd/javalib/framework-statsd.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission.jar:/apex/com.android.sdkext/javalib/framework-sdkextensions.jar:/apex/com.android.wifi/javalib/framework-wifi.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-tethering.jar', 'DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/framework-atb-backward-compatibility.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar:/system/framework/moto-echolocateapi.jar:/system/framework/payjoy-api.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/moto-telephony.jar:/system/framework/moto-core_services.jar:/system/framework/moto-settings.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/service-permission.jar:/apex/com.android.ipsec/javalib/android.net.ipsec.ike.jar', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '21', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_usap_pool_primary': '22', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app:/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'P4A_BOOTSTRAP': 'SDL2', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'P4A_IS_WINDOWED': 'True', 'P4A_ORIENTATION': 'portrait', 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
01-21 21:03:38.426 10162 10190 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. **name** is **main**
01-21 21:03:38.426 10162 10190 I python  : AND: Ran string
01-21 21:03:38.426 10162 10190 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
01-21 21:03:38.644 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-01-21_11.txt
01-21 21:03:38.645 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
01-21 21:03:38.646 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/**init**.pyc"
01-21 21:03:38.646 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.9 (main, Jan 21 2023, 00:35:37)
01-21 21:03:38.646 10162 10190 I python  : [Clang 14.0.6 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb
01-21 21:03:38.646 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
01-21 21:03:38.647 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
01-21 21:03:38.648 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
01-21 21:03:38.652 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.1, git-Unknown, 2023-01-17 (installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivymd/**init**.pyc")
01-21 21:03:38.657 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
01-21 21:03:39.837 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
01-21 21:03:39.889 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
01-21 21:03:40.299 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
01-21 21:03:40.459 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
01-21 21:03:40.481 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used 
01-21 21:03:40.482 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@0502.0 (GIT@704ecd9a2b, Ib3f3e69395, 1609240670) (Date:12/29/20)'>
01-21 21:03:40.485 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
01-21 21:03:40.486 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 610'>
01-21 21:03:40.489 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
01-21 21:03:40.493 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
01-21 21:03:40.498 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
01-21 21:03:40.554 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
01-21 21:03:40.557 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
01-21 21:03:46.146 10162 10190 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown  provider
01-21 21:03:46.146 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
01-21 21:03:46.190 10162 10190 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available

error log from MySQL

, 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
01-22 19:03:24.601  5217  5255 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. **name** is **main**
01-22 19:03:24.601  5217  5255 I python  : AND: Ran string
01-22 19:03:24.601  5217  5255 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
01-22 19:03:24.752  5217  5255 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 24)
01-22 19:03:24.752  5217  5255 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
01-22 19:03:24.757  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-01-22_0.txt
01-22 19:03:24.757  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
01-22 19:03:24.757  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/**init**.pyc"
01-22 19:03:24.757  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.9 (main, Jan 21 2023, 00:35:37)
01-22 19:03:24.757  5217  5255 I python  : [Clang 14.0.6 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb
01-22 19:03:24.758  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
01-22 19:03:24.758  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
01-22 19:03:24.759  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
01-22 19:03:24.761  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.1, git-Unknown, 2023-01-17 (installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.pakagapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivymd/**init**.pyc")
01-22 19:03:24.764  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
01-22 19:03:25.720  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
01-22 19:03:25.749  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
01-22 19:03:26.035  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
01-22 19:03:26.078  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
01-22 19:03:26.085  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used 
01-22 19:03:26.086  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@0502.0 (GIT@704ecd9a2b, Ib3f3e69395, 1609240670) (Date:12/29/20)'>
01-22 19:03:26.086  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
01-22 19:03:26.086  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 610'>
01-22 19:03:26.087  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
01-22 19:03:26.087  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
01-22 19:03:26.087  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
01-22 19:03:26.138  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
01-22 19:03:26.139  5217  5255 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
01-22 19:03:26.992  5217  5255 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
01-22 19:03:26.992  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/network.py", line 600, in open_connection
01-22 19:03:26.993  5217  5255 I python  :  ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
01-22 19:03:26.993  5217  5255 I python  :
01-22 19:03:26.993  5217  5255 I python  :  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
01-22 19:03:26.993  5217  5255 I python  :
01-22 19:03:26.994  5217  5255 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
01-22 19:03:26.994  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1033, in 
01-22 19:03:26.994  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 954, in run
01-22 19:03:26.994  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare
01-22 19:03:26.995  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1029, in build
01-22 19:03:26.995  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 305, in load_file
01-22 19:03:26.995  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 407, in load_string
01-22 19:03:26.995  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 660, in _apply_rule
01-22 19:03:26.996  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
01-22 19:03:26.996  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 540, in apply
01-22 19:03:26.996  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
01-22 19:03:26.997  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
01-22 19:03:26.997  5217  5255 I python  :    [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
01-22 19:03:26.997  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 658, in _apply_rule
01-22 19:03:26.997  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 659, in **init**
01-22 19:03:26.998  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/app/base_datos.py", line 75, in leer_tabla_cliente
01-22 19:03:26.998  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 294, in connect
01-22 19:03:26.998  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 167, in **init**
01-22 19:03:26.998  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1178, in connect
01-22 19:03:26.999  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 571, in _open_connection
01-22 19:03:26.999  5217  5255 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakag/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/pakagapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/network.py", line 602, in open_connection
01-22 19:03:26.999  5217  5255 I python  :  mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
01-22 19:03:26.999  5217  5255 I python  : Python for android ended.

Comment: Please post the last 50 lines from the app Error Log.

Comment: there I edited my question to show the app error log

Comment: Could you post last 50 lines of error log from MySQL?

Comment: I added it there

Comment: I just tried it on another phone and it works fine, I just have a few things out of place. Any recommendations to make it work on my phone or to know what the minimum requirements are?

Comment: What is hosting your MySQL server?  Windows or Linux?  View profile for contact info, please.